# Using robot_localization package

Tags: navigation, ekf, odometry, ros-hydro, gps-common

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm trying to use the `robot_localization` package in my project to improve my turtlebot pose estimate.

I've read the [package page](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) and the tutorials but I'm still confused in some parts:

1. In the package page it states that the *ekf_localization* is the only node in the package. However, in the [GPS integration tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization/Tutorials/GPS%20Integration) it is used *utm_transform_node*. Do I need to use both of them? Is *utm_transform_node* output one of the inputs for *ekf_localization*? If yes, should I use the same IMU data for both nodes?
2. I've attached a cellphone to the robot and I'm retrieving the data from its internal sensors. Since my GPS data is already in latitude/longitude format, may I just publish this data in the *fix* topic in the *utm_odometry_node* from the [gps_common](http://wiki.ros.org/gps_common) package? This way I wouldn't need to use the [nmea_navsat_driver](http://wiki.ros.org/nmea_navsat_driver) package.
3. I know I'm supposed to use the data from the cellphone accelerometer as my IMU data. But I'm also receiving the data from the inclinometer sensor which provides me roll/pitch/yaw angle values. Wouldn't this data be more useful than the one from the accelerometer? Could it be easily implemented in the position estimate?

I'm sorry for the several questions, but I'm quite new to ROS and some things are still not very clear to me.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190723/using-robot_localization-package/) by [gerhenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19473/gerhenz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2014-08-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take my answer with a pinch of salt, as I have started setting up `robot_localization` on my system, but I haven't tested it yet.

For question 1) Yes, you need to use both nodes. `utm_transform_node` will only broadcast a transform from global UTM coordinates to your robot's frame, and requires [nav_msgs/Odometry](http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Odometry.html) messages with raw UTM coordinates, so you also need `utm_odometry_node`. For the second part, yes, `utm_transform_node` should publish messages on the topic subscribed by `ekf_localization`. Lastly, yes, you may use the same IMU data for both nodes.

Regarding question 2) As long as you publish [sensor_msgs/NavSatFix](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/NavSatFix.html) messages populated with data from a GPS device (and a timestamp) on the topic subscribed by `utm_odometry_node`, you do not need `nmea_navsat_driver`.

Finally, question 3) Why not use both? You would need to configure both sensors with `robot_localization`, but fusion of an arbitrary number of sensors is claimed to be one of the advantages over `robot_pose_ekf`.

I'll post a comment once I have configured and tested my system with `robot_localization`.

---

Originally posted by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) with karma: 806 on 2014-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gerhenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19473/gerhenz/) on 2014-08-20**:
Everything is clearer now. Thanks Murilo!

**Comment by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) on 2014-08-21**:
It appears that `utm_transform_node` is missing (not installed) if the `robot_localization` package is installed using apt-get. There is an issue in the CMakeLists.txt. There is a pull request on github to fix this issue.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-08-24**:
This has been fixed in release x.1.4 (x is dependent upon your ROS version). It may take a week or two before the Debian packages are updated, so until then, just grab the [source](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization#Installing_robot_localization).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@Murilo F. M. already pretty much hit the nails on their respective heads. Re: (1), I need to update the documentation. *ekf_localization_node* was the only node at the time I wrote it, but then I added *utm_transform_node* to aid in GPS integration, and then neglected to update the wiki. For (3), robot_localization doesn't (yet) use linear accelerometer data. The only IMU data it uses is orientation and rotational velocity. If your accelerometers are also providing some estimate of orientation, then you can use both.

EDIT: However, *utm_transform_node* will want something with a yaw estimate, which probably won't be available from your accelerometer.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2014-08-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gerhenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19473/gerhenz/) on 2014-08-20**:
Therefore, I assume the best approach (at least for now) is to use the data from the inclinometer sensor since it provides the orientation angles of the robot. Thanks Tom!

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-08-20**:
That sounds correct to me. You're welcome!

**Comment by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) on 2014-08-20**:
Thanks a lot, Tom! It's good to know I'm going in the right direction.

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2014-12-30**:
Dear All, I dont have GPS Modeule, I have to use this package for Pose estimation, I am newbie plz help me in this. I am using Firebird robot

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-12-30**:
Please post your issue as a new question.